# Saving string from POST to existing mongoDB file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post

I have created a post request that receives a users ethereum address from the users end. Next I need to add the string to the users existing record in a mongoDB database.

```
app.post('/post', async (req,res) => {
    res.set({ 'Content-Length': 64 })
    res.json(req.body)
    const address = JSON.stringify(req.body.address)
    let temp = address.length-2;
    var walletAddress = address.slice(2, temp) //This is to remove brackets and speech marks from the string
    walletAddress = utils.getAddress(walletAddress)
    console.log(walletAddress);
    res.end("yes");
    //saving data in an existing mongodb
    
});
```

I've tried so many different ways and they have all presented an error off some kind.

Sorry if this is really obvious I am a noob, but help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what error are you getting? what payload are you sending? you need to provide at least that in a way to allow us to help you

Comment: @Derek Menénedez managed to make some progress. It recieves the data (a crypto wallet address) and saves it the mongodb, however, rather than it saving to the current users mongodb file it just overwrites it to the first user in the database.

**I added this code to the bottom of the function**

`//saving data in an existing mongodb
    console.log(req.user.id);
    let userdoc = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: req.user.id }, { address: walletAddress }).exec()
    console.log(userdoc);`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [official mongoDB driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). `npm install mongodb`

On their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)